# Koopman-Von Neumann Classical Mechanics From $C^*$-Algebra Approach?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, observables

My main question is the following:

> Is it possible to derive [Koopman-von Neumann (KvN) classical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics) from the $C^*$-Algebra approach to physics (as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra#C*-algebras_and_quantum_field_theory)) similar to how the usual quantum mechanics can be recovered from it?

By recover the usual quantum mechanics (from now on QM) from the $C^*$-Algebra approach i mean the following:

We can recover QM from the $C^*$-Algebra approach by choosing the [CCR $C^*$-Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_and_CAR_algebras#The_C*-algebra_of_CCR) (also known as the Weyl $C^*$-Algebra) as the $C^*$-Algebra of observables. It is then possible to recover the usual QM (in the simplest case $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with momentum and position operator) as a representation of the algebra of observables. It can further be shown that the GNS construction of any pure state is unitarily equivalent to the above representation. This is the [Stone-von Neumann Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem).

The details of this construction can be found in example 8.25 in the book "Fundamental Mathematical
Structures of Quantum
Theory" by Valter Moretti and in the work "Spectral Theory
and Quantum
Mechanics" by the same author.

- What would the correct choice of algebra of observables be to obtain KvN mechanics similar to how QM is obtained in the above procedure? Presumably it is related to [the KvN commutation relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics#math_KvN_algebra) mentioned in the wikipedia article in some sort of exponentiated form?